# What is GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS?

Tags: opengl, c++, graphics-programming

I am a beginner in OpenGL. I am learning about **textures** in OpenGL. What I don't understand is how to determine how many texture units are in the GPU. I heard someone said that you can see how many texture units by writing the following code.

```
int total_units;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &total_units);
std::cout << total_units << '\n';  // the result is 192
```

Is there 192 texture units in my GPU?  In [documentation](https://docs.gl/gl3/glGet), it says:

> GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS
> params returns one value, the maximum supported texture image units that can be used to access texture maps from the vertex shader and the fragment processor combined. If both the vertex shader and the fragment processing stage access the same texture image unit, then that counts as using two texture image units against this limit. The value must be at least 48. See glActiveTexture.

So I wanted to know how many texture units can be used to access texture maps from the vertex and fragment shaders. So I wrote and run the following code.

```
int vertex_units, fragment_units;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &vertex_units);
std::cout << vertex_units << "\n";   // the result is 32
glGetInteferv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &fragment_units);
std::cout << fragment_units << "\n"; // the result is also 32
```

So 32+32=64. But why does `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` shows me the result of 192? I think I am missing something. What do I need to calculate to get 192?

And also, in OpenGL, why are there only `GL_TEXTURE0` to `GL_TEXTURE31` macros? I think these macros are for each shaders. Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

> What do I need to calculate to get 192?

You need to recognize the fact that there are more than 2 shader stages. OpenGL 4.5 has *six* programmable stages: vertex, tessellation control, tessellation evaluation, geometry, fragment, and compute. Each of them can access some number of textures, and the "combined" value specifies how many can be accessed by all stages in total.

> why are there only GL_TEXTURE0 to GL_TEXTURE31 macros?

The proper way to set the active texture unit is with the value `GL_TEXTURE0 + i`, where `i` is the texture unit index. All of the macros 1 to 31 are monotonically increasing in value, so `GL_TEXTURE0 + 5` is the same value as `GL_TEXTURE5`.

So to set the active texture unit, use `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);`.

Basically, OpenGL only defines 32 macros because they never needed to define more than 1. The other 31 are just for the sake of convenience.

Comment: OpenGL 4.5 uses texture names and binds them to units. Units are referenced in the shaders. No active texture is needed. And macros can be defined at any time, they are not limited to utility headers.

Comment: @a_donda: All versions of OpenGL use "texture names" (ie: the things you get from `glGen/CreateTextures`. And all versions of OpenGL allow you to bind them to texture units (which happens whenever you call `glBindTexture`).

Comment: The 4.5 apis are glCreateTextures() and glBindTextureUnit(), and they avoid much of the confusion that comes up with older style, like the one how come the different unit numbers to be. The docu mentions only vertex- and fragment stage.

Comment: @a_donda: "*The docu mentions nowhere the stages other than vertex- and fragment.*" I don't know what "docu" you are referring to, but the OpenGL specification has recognized more than 2 shader stages since GL 3.2. And we've had 6 stages since 4.3. Can you link to the "docu" that says there are only vertex and fragment shader stages?

Comment: @a_donda: "*The 4.5 apis are glCreateTextures() and glBindTextureUnit(), and they avoid much of the confusion that comes up with older style*" Sure, but that's not what the OP asked about, so while it is better form, it's rather orthogonal to the point of the question.

Comment: @nicol: Now I know that the value 192 comes from 32 * 6 stages. So that value depends only on my graphics card and not what I wrote the code,`glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
 glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);`  which will be GL 3.3.

Comment: @PhoneMyatPyaeSone: Just because you ask for GL 3.3 doesn't mean you will get *only* 3.3. Implementations are allowed to give you any version of OpenGL that is 100% backwards compatible with 3.3. And since all versions of GL 3.2 and greater are backwards compatible with 4.6, it could just give you 4.6.

Comment: @NicolBolas when you say "Each of them can access some number of textures" do you mean that each one of them _can_ access some number but they can chose not to? And if they chose not to, then can the pixel shader (for e.g.) use `192` texture units?

Comment: @Samaursa: Each stage has its own limit to the number of textures it can access. That's why this is the "COMBINED" value; it represents the total number of texture units.

Comment: @NicolBolas makes sense and that clears up part of my confusion.